# ng-repeat in ng-repeat, scope not change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

[Question Link Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iWTkPrDDvrDdc4LRQjTN?p=preview)

http://plnkr.co/edit/iWTkPrDDvrDdc4LRQjTN?p=preview

code is like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="line in lines">
      <div ng-repeat="action in actions" format>{{action.content}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
      .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.lines = [
          ['11', '12', '13'],
          ['21', '22', '23'],
          ['31', '32', '33']
        ];
        $scope.actions = [{
          content: '{0}'
        }, {
          content: '{2}'
        }];
      })
      .directive('format', function() {
        return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
          scope.action.content = scope.action.content.replace(/\{\d+\}/g, function(number) {
            return scope.line[number.slice(1, -1)];
          });
          //scope.action.content = 1;
        };
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*but why the result is*: 
11
13
11
13
11
13

I expect it is 
11
13
21
23
31
33

why the line not change?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting is the job of a [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter), not directive. Try:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="line in lines">
      <div ng-repeat="action in actions">{{line | format:action.content }}</div> //Change this line to use filter to format output
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
      .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.lines = [
          ['11', '12', '13'],
          ['21', '22', '23'],
          ['31', '32', '33']
        ];
        $scope.actions = [{
          content: '{0}'
        }, {
          content: '{2}'
        }];
      })
      .filter('format', function() { //Create a filter
        return function(line,content) {
          return content.replace(/\{\d+\}/g, function(number) {
            return line[number.slice(1, -1)];
          });
          //scope.action.content = 1;
        };
      });
  </script>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/mvtLQHlW9C50chAuyvBp?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="line in lines">
    {{line[0]}} {{line[2]}}
      <!-- <div ng-repeat="action in line" format>{{action}}</div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

I think for your case you don't even need the actions. Just do it like this.

Comment: yeah, you are right. But in fact, I need actions to format line. Like action is {content:'hello{1}'}, so, i hope the result turn into "hello11 hello13...." you know..

Comment: thats totally fine. do it like {{hello+line[0]}} and {{hello+line[2]}}